# Editor freezes with Instantiate() in Unity 2019

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My game has a home scene and two game scenes (SceneA & SceneB). Editor freezes when moving from Home Scene to SceneA with SceneManager.LoadScene().

So, I checked the code of SceneA. Then I noticed that the editor was frozen in one place.

The following code is for scene A.

```
//SceneA Script

[SerializeField]
float range;
[SerializeField]
GameObject obj;

void Start()
{
    Spawn();
}

void Spawn()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 99; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(obj, new Vector3(Random.Range(-range, range), 0.5f, Random.Range(-range, range)), Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

If I remove Spawn(), it will not freeze. But I need to create 99 obj objects.
Suddenly it started to freeze even though it was done a while ago.

Also, SceneB was loading normally until this problem occurred, but now when you try to SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneB) after this problem, it freezes.

Is this a Unity bug? Is the player setting involved? The reason that SceneB cannot be read is that there is a problem with terminating the editor task when it freezes in SceneA?

I'm really in trouble because I don't see any errors. somebody help me please.

Comment: Well `Instantiat`ing 100 objects simply takes a while. Especially if all these objects also have some components we don't know that might take a while ... did you make etremly sure that the spawned objects do not have the same script attached and every object spawns another 100 objects e.g.? ;) What do you mean by `freeze` .. does it simply take some time or does it never terminate?

Comment: Does something speak against already having all these objects in your scene from the beginning and only update their positions?

Answer (score 0):

I caused this problem by one small mistake. 
Perhaps this question is useless for others who get Unity frozen by SceneManager.LoadScene().

My failure:

There was a mistake in the script for objects created by Instantiate().

```
//freeze code
void Start()
{
     StartCoroutine("Load");
}
IEnumarator Load()
{
    yield return new WaitFOrSeconds(2);
    while(true)
    {
        //Something heavy processing
    }
}
```

It is natural to freeze.